Crontab task execution
I am trying to run a simple script through a crontab task but nothing is run. Any error is displayed. I make the following:

Create a simple script with the following code: echo "Hola mundo". I name the
script hola.sh.

I want this script to be run using crontab. I type crontab -e and I copy the following line, where tmp is a directory created in my diectory, /home/alex:
15 * * * * /tmp/cat hola.sh



When minut 15 arrive, nothing is displayed. The logs are not indicating errors:

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Please don't post images of text.

You may or may not have tmp in your home, but your 2nd crontab entry is referencing /tmp, which is under the root directory /, not under /home/alex.
You also seem to just have separated the directory entry from the command cat with a space, that isn't going to work.
As for no error ... check your mail. The output of commands in crontab doesn't end up in the logs.
Try the following:
15 * * * * /bin/cat /home/alex/hola.sh

That, however, also won't produce any visible output by default; you'll need to check it in your local mail.

Thanks for the answer. I tried to change what you point me and it does not run. I changed the crontab code: 58 * * * * tmp/cat hola.sh and it did not run.

@axmug - no, that won't work, either. Try it tmp/cat hola.sh on the command line and you'll get an error message, too. I'll add an invocation that should work to my answer.

The script location was not clearly specified.
If the tmp directory you named is really a subfolder of /home/alex then
you can move the script in it and then it may be invoked using its absolute path:
/home/alex/tmp/hola.sh

please check if this script is executable by your user, i.e.
if the ls -l command returns a "x" as 4th character
ls -l /home/alex/tmp/hola.sh
-rwxr-x--- alex alex 220 2021-04-26 11:55:21 /home/alex/tmp/hola.sh

if not, you can fix it with chmod u+x /home/alex/tmp/hola.sh
then the involved entry in crontab should be similar to
15 * * * * /home/alex/tmp/hola.sh

the cron job output is usually sent via email, but the error in the screenshot you posted also reports that the email system is now working ("no MTA installed..."): you can then collect the output (both stdout and sterr) using
the normal redirection:
15 * * * * /home/alex/tmp/hola.sh >/home/alex/tmp/output.txt 2>&1


I have tried everything you point it and it does not run yet. I don't know what to do
